# After clicking Hangout button "gapi.hangout.getStartData()" returns null

Tags: google-hangouts

Using The Hangout Api. I have integrated hangout button and passed parameters using

```
  gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-div1', {
    'render': 'createhangout',
    'hangout_type': 'onair',
    'initial_apps': [{
    'app_id': '1234566', //renders intially hangout app when hangout starts
    'start_data': "654321", //reference  which is present on the page 
    'app_type': 'ROOM_APP'
        }]
     </code>
  // on my xml the script code is:
   <code> 
     function init() {
     // When API is ready...
    gapi.hangout.onApiReady.add(
    function(eventObj) {
    document.getElementById('showParticipants')
        .style.visibility = 'visible';
        startup();
   });
  }
 function startup(){
 try{
  gapi.hangout.onair.onYouTubeLiveIdReady.add(function(liveId){
    var id = gapi.hangout.onair.getYouTubeLiveId();
    var Id= gapi.hangout.getStartData(); //here Id is null
  }
}
```

Previously when i use gapi.hangout.getStartData(). I got "start_data" parameters from      my "initial_apps".I think hangout have changed there interface. and now gapi.hangout.getstartData() is  getting  null value.

I Don't know what is wrong. Please suggest me for a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

It happens mostly when the app doesn't get loaded when you start the hangout and you click on the app icon inside the hangout manually after the hangout is started.

From

```
https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout#gapi.hangout.getStartData
```

getStartData() - Gets the starting data for the current active app. This is the data passed in by the gd URL parameter (also available with gadgets.views.getParams). Returns null if no start data has been specified.

Try using 
gadgets.views.getParams  and see if the problem persists

Update--
Try getting the start_data manually

Add the following script to get the query paramters

```
<script>
var qs = (function(a) {
if (a == "") return {};
var b = {};
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
{
    var p=a[i].split('=', 2);
    if (p.length == 1)
        b[p[0]] = "";
    else
        b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
return b;
})(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'));
```

And then use the following to get the start data which is passed as gd query parameter

```
var hangoutstartdata = qs["gd"]
```

Comment: Yes , I have tried with gadgets.views.getParams but it was not working  , The app was loading with no problem but i am unable to get the 'start_data' value.

Comment: @sitaram9292 try to put your start data in single qoutes 'start_data': '654321'

Comment: Yes it was in single quotes in my working code . The problem is i am unable to get the parameters which i send from my application.

Comment: where did you pass the gd query parameter

Comment: @sitaram9292 Your start_data will be received as gd paramter

Comment: have you seen the new interface changes done to hangout , where we need to share over video and than again we need to click on start button in than share video , I think in between than process we are missing the start_data values

Comment: Now i am able to get the start_data with gapi.hangout.getStartData(). As the hangout changed its interface to the old one. Thank you very much for all the help, I am thinking that the problem will come back when hangout again change its interface.

Comment: @sitaram9292 Nice. May be there are testing some features.

Comment: this trick did not work for us.  After closer inspection, it's pretty clear that `gd` is undefined.  But we are trying to start our custom app *after* the hangout gets started.  I'll try to post more once we setup our app as one of the defaults in the `app_id`.  I suspect that'll solve the issue.